# Can "gnome-network-displays" work on a Ubuntu 20.04.3 running on Oracle VM VirtualBox

Tags: networking, 20.04, gnome, virtualbox, display

I am trying to simulate casting my display to a miracast sink on linux. It seem like [gnome-network-displays](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-network-displays) is a good option. I was having trouble getting it to work and was not sure if the fact I am running linux on a virtual machine on my windows device was the issue. It that an inherent problem?

Comment: Where is the sink located? How is networking set up for your VM?

Answer (score 0):

You have to compile the `gnome-network-displays` [application](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-network-displays) first as it is [does not](https://repology.org/project/gnome-network-displays/versions) available in deb-package form for modern Ubuntu releases. One can use PKGBUILD from ArchLinux as [prototype](https://aur.archlinux.org/cgit/aur.git/tree/PKGBUILD?h=gnome-network-displays-git).
To compile and install use the commands below:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install git build-essential debhelper gnome-pkg-tools libglib2.0-dev libgstreamer1.0-dev libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-dev libgstrtspserver-1.0-dev libgtk-3-dev libnm-dev libpulse-dev libx264-dev meson wpasupplicant desktop-file-utils appstream-util

cd ~/Downloads
git clone https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-network-displays
cd gnome-network-displays.git
meson compile
meson test --print-errorlogs
meson install -C build
```

Then you have to switch the virtualbox network adapter to the bridge as shown below

[image: bridged networking in Virtualbox machine settings]

and it should work.

---

Note for Ubuntu 18.04 LTS users - here are packages from [some PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Emiurahr/+archive/ubuntu/wifi-p2p) instead of compiling.

Comment: with the current meson version 0.61.2 i can not compile:
ERROR: Current directory is not a meson build directory: `/home/.../Downloads/gnome-network-displays`.
Please specify a valid build dir or change the working directory to it.
It is also possible that the build directory was generated with an old
meson version. Please regenerate it in this case.

Comment: @nnov Same here.

Comment: Try `meson build && cd build && meson install`